# formating the email body in a vbs script for sending email

Tags: bash, email, vbscript

I am working of creating a file that checks the difference between 2 files using `diff` in bash:

```
$ echo "they're different" > recordchange.txt
$ echo "$(diff --width=120 -y $f1 $f2)" >> recordchange.txt
```

This gives me an output file that looks like this in notpad++:
(opening it in notepad on windows7 is worse formatting due to line endings see [here)](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux)

```
they're different
"KPI1"                                                      "KPI1"
"KPI2 with a different length - but different"         |    "KPI2 with a different length"
"KPI3 with a and even different length"                     "KPI3 with a and even different length"
"KPI4 with a and even longer different length"              "KPI4 with a and even longer different length"
```

Now what I am trying to do is email this in the body of an email and keep the same format using `vbs`. But the I can not get the format to be the same after doing numerous searching and no joy.

This is a snippet of my code that creates the email body taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726067/how-does-this-script-sending-email-using-outlook-work):

```
newMail.BodyFormat = 1 '1=Plain text, 2=HTML 3=RichText 
newMail.Body = text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & MessageBody & vbCrLf & MyTime
'newMail.HTMLBody = "<html><body><code>" + text + "</code></body></html>"
```

**Is there anyway I can have the format the same in the email body as the text file?**

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer attaching a text file instead of embedding in e-mail body, but there is the `<pre>` tag which defines preformatted text, it could help...

Text in a `<pre>` element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks. Use the `<pre>` element when displaying text with unusual formatting, or some sort of computer code.

So your code could be as follows:

```
newMail.HTMLBody = "<html><body><pre>" + text + "</pre></body></html>"
```

Comment: that helps, but it is still not perfect, but maybe it is he best that can be done. tks